# String must contain only [a-zA-Z0-9_] symbols (may be from one letter but not "_"), start not from digit

Tags: java, regex

I'm solving a problem in Java and need to make a regexp, which checks the string for the next rules:

1. the string must contain only digits, uppercase and lowercase letters and underscore character `"_"`;
2. the string must not start from digit;
3. if the string starts from underscore, the second character must be not underscore, i.e it must be a digit or a letter;
4. the string may consist only from one character but this character must not be an underscore;

I do not understand how to make the first part of regexp. I tried to make it part by part:

1. Expression `"_[a-zA-Z0-9]"` satisfies the condition "If string starts from underscore character then the second character is a letter or digit".
2. Expression `"\\D"` satisfies the condition "String must not start from a digit".
3. Expression `"[a-zA-Z]"` satisfies the condition "String starts from an uppercase or lowercase letter".

The last part of expression is simple - `"w*"`.

When I try to put all this together `"(_[a-zA-Z0-9])*|(\\D)*|([a-zA-Z])*w*"`, the obtained regexp does not work properly.

The following strings `b33` and `_n1` do not fit for my regexp but the string `__` fits to it.

How to fix my regexp?

Comment: Note that `w` only matches `w` char, not word chars, you should have used `\w`. However, `\D*` will match strings that are all non-digits, `(_[a-zA-Z0-9])*`  matches strings like `_a_1_b_4_t`... `([a-zA-Z])*w*` will match any letter only strings. This is rather a corrupt pattern as you see.

Comment: Thank you, I understood where I've got errors using your solution. I used the following regular expression: `(_[a-zA-Z\\d]|[a-zA-Z]\\w*)\\w*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?![0-9]|__|_$)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$
```

Or, with shorthands:

```
^(?!\d|__|_$)\w+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eTa7mL/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string (implicit in `.matches()`)
- `(?![0-9]|__|_$)` - right after, there can't be a digit or `__` substring, or `_` followed with end of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` - 1+ ASCII letters, digits or `_` (use `*` to match an empty string, too)
- `$` - end of string (implicit in `.matches()`).

In Java, use it with `.matches()` omitting the anchors:

```
s.matches("(?!\\d|__|_$)\\w+")
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Wiktor is correct and compact. nevertheless I would like to offer an alternative which only partially uses regex. Often I have also searched online for a compact regex and often get an answer but two months later I have no idea what the expression means.

If you are not a regex genius like Wiktor Stribiżew and would like to see at first glance what has been validated, I suggest you the following approach

```
static boolean check(String s){
    if(s.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_]+")){
        if( !Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0))){
            if(!s.startsWith("__")){
                return !(s.length() == 1 && s.equals("_"));
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```